# What is cloudfront link?

Tags: docker, amazon-cloudfront

I'm making dockerfile, and to install spark there is two links that I can use.

```
A. http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
B. https://www.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.1.0/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
```

I think 'B' is official link but most dockerfile that I looked up are with 'A'.
'B' link is permanent? What's different between them?

Comment: Cloudfront is Amazon's CDN, and part of AWS.

Comment: So, link 'A' is personal link that might be deleted anytime?

Comment: It depends who set it up.  It could have been set up by Apache, but I'd be surprised if apache.org wasn't behind a CDN anyway.  The Cloudfront link also isn't secure.

Comment: thanks I better to use apache link.